# Scikit learn Kmeans assigning a label to input data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, k-means

I want to assign a label to each input data; for example, data[0] is 'k', data[2] is 'b', data [5] is 'j', data[13] is another 'k',....etc.

After doing the clustering displayed here:  [3D plot of 2 clusters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saVU7.png), I want to retrieve the type of each "point label" in every cluster.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

data = np.array([[-7.82,4.58,-3.97],[-6.68,3.16,2.71],
[4.36,-2.19,2.09],[6.72,0.88,2.80],
[-8.64,3.06,3.50],[-6.87,0.57,-5.45],
[4.47,-2.62,5.76],[6.73,-2.01,4.18],
[-7.71,2.34,-6.33],[-6.91,-0.49,-5.68],
[6.18,2.81,5.82],[6.72,-0.93,-4.04],
[-6.25,-0.26,0.56],[-6.94,-1.22,1.13],
[8.09,0.20,2.25],[6.81,0.17,-4.15],
[-5.19,4.24,4.04],[-6.38,-1.74,1.43],
[4.08,1.30,5.33],[6.27,0.93,-2.78]])


centers = np.array([[1,1,1],[-1,1,-1]])
model_ = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init = centers, n_init=1).fit(data)
print('The labels for Part a are %s' % model_.labels_)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1],  data[:,2],c=model_.labels_.astype(float),s=70)
plt.title('Visualizing Clusters')
ax.set_xlabel('X1', fontsize = 10)
ax.set_ylabel('X2', fontsize = 10)
ax.set_zlabel('X3', fontsize = 10)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the labels with `labels = model_.labels_`. And you can, for example, count the number of 'lefts' on cluster zero with `sum(labels[0:9] == 0)`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I edited the question, perhaps it's more clear now.

Comment: Just create an array with the labels of each data point, respecting the order in the `data` array. `assigned_labels = np.array(['k', 'b', ...',k', ...])`. As an example, `sum(labels[assigned_labels == 'k'] == 0)` will return the number of elements with label 'k' that were assigned to cluster `0`.

Comment: I'm not sure what that returns! I tried: labels = np.array([2, 0, 1]) and assigned_labels = np.array(['k', 'b',',k']) , labels[assigned_labels == 'k'] returns array([2]) , labels[assigned_labels == 'b'] returns array([0]).

Comment: These arrays are the cluster labels of elements of type `'k'` and type `'b'`. Now you can count then by `sum(labels[assigned_labels == 'k'] == cluster_label)`.

Comment: Well then that simply doesn't work because A) it ignored the second K, B) I want to retrieve the types in a certain class, not the class of a certain type.

Comment: It have not ignored the second `k`, the second `k` you gave has a comma in it. Just do the things in the opposite order `assigned_labels[labels == 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign letters to rows you can use pandas for example.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> indexes = [chr(ord('a') + i) for i in range(data.shape[0])]
>>> indexes
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't']
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(data, index=indexes) # pass your old data variable
>>> data
      0     1     2
a -7.82  4.58 -3.97
b -6.68  3.16  2.71
c  4.36 -2.19  2.09
d  6.72  0.88  2.80
e -8.64  3.06  3.50
f -6.87  0.57 -5.45
g  4.47 -2.62  5.76
h  6.73 -2.01  4.18
i -7.71  2.34 -6.33
j -6.91 -0.49 -5.68
k  6.18  2.81  5.82
l  6.72 -0.93 -4.04
m -6.25 -0.26  0.56
n -6.94 -1.22  1.13
o  8.09  0.20  2.25
p  6.81  0.17 -4.15
q -5.19  4.24  4.04
r -6.38 -1.74  1.43
s  4.08  1.30  5.33
t  6.27  0.93 -2.78
>>> data.loc['a']
0   -7.82
1    4.58
2   -3.97
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

As the output of models_.labels_ will be exactly in the order of input, you can just create a list that stores additional label information parallely to your input list.

(from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

```
>>> from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 4], [1, 0],
...               [10, 2], [10, 4], [10, 0]])
>>> kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, random_state=0).fit(X)
>>> kmeans.labels_
array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Note that label output matches your input order.